# NodeJS, динамические импорты

Tags: javascript, node.js, dynamic

Почему так работает: `import sslkeylog from "sslkeylog";`,
а так - нет?

```
async function debug() {
        let {sslkeylog} = await import('sslkeylog')
        sslkeylog.setLog('./ssldebug.log').hookAll();
}
debug();
```

Comment: очевидно потому что в первом случае ты используешь дефолтный импорт, а во втором - свойство

Comment: поставь в первом фигурные скобки `import {sslkeylog} from "sslkeylog"` и он тоже перестанет работать

Comment: и? теперь работает?

Comment: Очевидно не работает. Потому что правильно так: `const { default: sslkeylog } = await import('sslkeylog');` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Importing_defaults

Comment: @Alexey Ten, ты лучший!

Comment: @AlexeyTen, по идее не должно быть разницы

Comment: А твоя версия Node.js поддерживает динамические импорты?

Comment: @Grundy почему? Это прямым текстом в документации написано «When importing a default export with dynamic imports, it works a bit differently. You need to destructure and rename the "default" key from the returned object.»

Comment: @AlexeyTen, ага, не видел эту часть :)